# Min, Max, Avg for 2-hour intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate, generate-series

In below query, I am calculating the minimum, the maximum, and the average for a two hour interval using PostgreSQL.

The query works fine for even start hours `(..04:00:00+05:30)`, but it gives similar result as that of even start time for odd start hours `(..05:00:00+05:30)`.
The multiple by 2 returns even hours which is the problem.

```
SELECT tagid, CAST(sample_time_stamp as Date) AS stat_date, 
       (floor(extract(hour from sample_time_stamp)/2) * 2)::int AS hrs,
       min(sensor_reading) AS theMin,   
       max(sensor_reading) AS theMax,
       avg(sensor_reading) AS theAvg
FROM sensor_readings WHERE tagid =1 AND 
sample_time_stamp BETWEEN '2012-10-23 01:00:00+05:30'
                  AND     '2012-10-23 05:59:00+05:30'
GROUP BY tagid,CAST(sample_time_stamp as Date),
         floor(extract(hour from sample_time_stamp)/2) * 2
ORDER BY tagid,stat_date, hrs
```

#### OutPut for Odd start Hour ('2012-10-23 01:00:00+05:30')

```
tagid    date          hrs  theMin  themax    theAvg 
1        2012-10-23    0    6       58        30.95
1        2012-10-23    2    2       59        29.6916666666667
1        2012-10-23    4    3       89        31.7666666666667
```

#### OutPut for Even start Hour ('2012-10-23 02:00:00+05:30')

```
tagid    date          hrs  theMin   themax    theAvg
1        2012-10-23    2    2        59        29.6916666666667
1        2012-10-23    4    3        89        31.7666666666667
```

Comment: As *always*, table definition and version of PostgreSQL are relevant, too

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I *really* wish SO would let us parameterize tags, so when the `postgresql` tag is used it nags the user "Please enter your PostgreSQL version here: ` and reminds them to add table definitions, desired output, explain analyze for performance questions, etc. SO says it wants good quality questions and penalizes bad ones, then makes it hard for new users to work out what a good question is...

Comment: @CraigRinger: I proposed [a very similar feature in a discussion on meta to disambiguate the SQL tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110371/169168) a while back. So you can guess I like the idea. But it would have to be a gentle reminder, like the reminder in an E-Mail client to add an attachment once you mention "attachment". Shouldn't keep people from posting simple questions. This is stuff for meta, though, and strictly OT here ..

Answer (score 3):

To get constant time-frames starting with your minimum timestamp:

```
WITH params AS (
   SELECT '2012-10-23 01:00:00+05:30'::timestamptz AS _min  -- input params
         ,'2012-10-23 05:59:00+05:30'::timestamptz AS _max
         ,'2 hours'::interval                      AS _interval
   )
  ,ts AS (SELECT generate_series(_min, _max, _interval) AS t_min FROM params)
  ,timeframe AS (
   SELECT t_min
         ,lead(t_min, 1, _max) OVER (ORDER BY t_min) AS t_max
   FROM ts, params
   )
SELECT s.tagid
      ,t.t_min
      ,t.t_max     -- mildly redundant except for last row
      ,min(s.sensor_reading) AS the_min
      ,max(s.sensor_reading) AS the_max
      ,avg(s.sensor_reading) AS the_avg
FROM   timeframe t
LEFT   JOIN sensor_readings s ON  s.tagid = 1
                              AND s.sample_time_stamp >= t.t_min
                              AND s.sample_time_stamp <  t.t_max
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Can be used for *any* time frame and *any* interval length. Requires PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.

If the maximum timestamp `_max` does not fall on `_min + n * _interval` the last time-frame is truncated. The last row can therefore represent a shorter time-frame than your desired `_interval`.

#### Key elements

- [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) for easier handling. Input parameter values  *once* in the top CTE `params`.
- [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) for intervals to create the time raster.
- [Window function `lead(...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) with 3 parameters (including default) - to cover the special case of last row.
- `LEFT JOIN` between raster and actual data, so that time frames without matching data will still show in the result (with `NULL` values as data).
  That's also the reason for a later edit: `WHERE` condition had to move to the `LEFT JOIN` condition, to achieve that.

#### Alternative time frame generation with recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE params AS (
   SELECT '2012-10-23 01:00:00+05:30'::timestamptz AS _min  -- input params
         ,'2012-10-23 05:59:00+05:30'::timestamptz AS _max
         ,'2 hours'::interval                      AS _interval
   )
   , timeframe AS (
   SELECT _min AS t_min, LEAST(_min + _interval, _max) AS t_max
   FROM   params

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT t_max, LEAST(t_max + _interval, _max)
   FROM   timeframe t, params p
   WHERE  t_max < _max
   )
SELECT ...
```

Slightly faster ... take your pick.
[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/71568/5) displaying both.

Note that you can have *non-recursive* CTEs (additionally) even when declared `WITH RECURSIVE`.

#### Performance & Index

Should be faster than your original query. Half the code deals with generating the time raster, which concerns few rows and is *very* fast. Handling actual table rows (the expensive part) gets cheaper, because we don't calculate a new value from every `sample_time_stamp` any more.

You should definitely have a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON sensor_readings (tagid, sample_time_stamp DESC);
```

I use `DESC` on the assumption that you more often query recent entries (later timestamps). Remove the modifier if that's not the case. Doesn't make a big difference either way.